# Is it ok to place a window AC unit in front of the window instead of hanging outside?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I just put a window AC unit on a table in front of a window instead of hanging out of the window. The back is flush with where the screen would be so the heat is pumping outside.. but the side vents that are normally outside the house are in the house. Is there an issue with this? The AC unit is just about 1 inch too big to fit fully out the window...but the back is flush with the frame.

Thanks

Kelly[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Those vents are probably there for a reason, and the reason probably assumes that they'll be outside. Other than that, we probably can't say without more information (e.g. can you feel air being blown out of or sucked into these vents?).

Comment: They suck in air, I just uploaded the post to have a picture

Answer (score 5):

This should work, except there are some potential problems:

- Usually a window A/C gets rid of the indoor heat by taking outside air and heating it, discharging it outside. Here, you're taking inside air and heating it (still discharging it outside). This will work, and it's exactly how single-hose indoor air conditioners work. However, it's less efficient (perhaps a lot less efficient).
- The evaporator coil (that cools the indoor air) also condenses water, which has to be disposed of outside through a drain. It's quite possible that the normally-outside drain is now inside, and you're going to find an increasingly large puddle on your floor.
- Your A/C will likely be noisier than it usually is (at least indoors, but that's where it counts).

So, it'll work, but there may be issues (the water one being the most immediately concerning).

Comment: Thank you for your input! I do have a tube taking water outside... this isn't going to be a long term thing... just trying to get through the heat wave that seems o be across all of Canada!

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off placing the unit on a shelf or bracket *outside* the window with the *front* flush with the frame.

Most modern ACs draw inside air through a filter across the front, and blow the cooled air back into the room through a directed vent. Such a unit would work efficiently if placed outside a window. Provided, of course, that it didn't fall off its shelf and commit an injury tort below.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have a tube draining the water outside. This is just a temporary solution to a relentless heat wave and is not intended to be used for very long. Just trying to take the edge off a bit!

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea and it would seem to work with one exception - pulling air from inside the room rather than outside.  it starts to work like the max AC option on my car AC.  The pathway is hot room air blowing over cold Freon, cold air blows back into the room and the warm Freon is compressed (more heat) and cooled (to get rid of the compressor heat) with outside air coming in the side vents and blowing out the back.  The Freon temp is brought down to frigid by expansion, run through the radiator in the front and the whole process starts over.  Sounds like a great solution and definitely on my short list.  Especially because my new, expensive, Marvin windows warranty specifically says you can't use an outside the window AC or you'll void the warranty.  Thanks for the suggestion and the picture.  Now all I need is a nice strong person to haul the thing from my bedroom down to the cellar every winter.

Comment: You basically answered the question but added a whole lot of extra verbiage. clean it up a bit.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please take the [tour] to understand how this Question & Answer site differs from your run-of-the-mill discussion forum. Also, if you'll look through the "how to answer" section of the [help], you'll see what is expected in an answer. As JACK indicated you've answered, but it's not quite up to expectations around here. Please [edit] to clean it up, you you're likely to get some up votes which will earn you some rep and some additional privileges.